# ReactJS - How to properly initialize state from props which is populated by fetching data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my editing component:

```
class EditField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: '' };
  }
  edit(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      this.props.onEdited(this.state.value);
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.value}
          onChange={this.edit.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I need to populate state from props like this:

```
function Container({ entity, onEdited }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <EditField onEdited={onEdited} value={entity.firstName} />
      <EditField onEdited={onEdited} value={entity.lastName} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The `Container` component get `onEdited` and `entity` props from redux store.
`Container`'s parent will handle data fetching and `onEdited` (which will
only be triggered if user hit `Enter`) will `dispatch` request to the server.

My problem is how to initialize `value` props properly? Because if I use:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      value: this.props.value
    });
  }
```

I got empty state because fetching data is not finished when `componentDidMount`
called. And if I use:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      value: nextProps.value
    });
  }
```

I got this warning:

```
Warning: EditField is changing a controlled input of type text to be
unncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.
```

So, how to do this correctly?

Comment: Could you add all of your code seems like something is missing

Comment: You're getting this warning, when trying to update state in `componentWillReceiveProps`, because you possible removed `onChange` event handler from `input` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I recommend:

- You could use `getInitialState` from EditField to populate the `value` state from the `value` prop. But this won't work, because `getInitialState` will only be called once, so subsequent renders will not update the state. Besides, [this is an anti-pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html).
- You should make the `EditField` component controlled. Always pass the current `value` as prop and stop dealing with state at all. If you want a library to help you *link* the input state with Redux, please take a look at [Redux-Form](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/?_k=xv9qpo).
- The `onEdited` event you created, at least the way you did it, doesn't play well with controlled inputs, so, what you want to do is to have an `onChange` event that is always fired with the new value, so the Redux state will always change. You *may* have another event triggered when the user hits enter (e.g `onEnterPressed`), so you can call the server and update the entity values. Again. Redux-Form can help here.
- Apparently `entity.firstName` and `entity.lastName` can only contain the values that the user has confirmed (hit enter), not temporary values. If this is the case, try to separate the state of the form from the state of the entity. The state of the form can be controlled by Redux-Form. When the user hits enter, you can trigger an action that actually calls the server and updates the state of the entity. You can even have a "loading" state so your form is disabled while you're calling the server.

Answer (score 2):

Since Container subscribes to Redux store, I suggest make the EditField stateless functional component. Here's my approach:

```
const EditField = ({
  onEdited,
  value
}) => (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={onEdited}
      />
    </div>
);

class Container extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }

  edit = (e) => {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
    e.keyCode === 13 ? this.props.onEdited(this.state.value) : null;
  };

  sendValue = (val) => val ? val : this.state.value;

  render() {
    this.props = {
      firstName: "Ilan",
      lastName: null
    }
    let { firstName, lastName, onEdited } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <EditField onEdited={this.edit} value={this.sendValue(firstName)} />
        <EditField onEdited={this.edit} value={this.sendValue(lastName)} />
      </div>      
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

A live demo: https://codepen.io/ilanus/pen/yJQNNk

Container will send either firstName, lastName or the default state...